# Any way to create files inside a submodule but commit them to a parent repository?

Tags: python, git, pytest

I have some framework located in a separate repository, which I want to use in the main repository.

The problem is I have to put my programs inside the framework in order for them to work, and I need to commit these programs to the main repository because they are a part of not the framework but the main project.

For example, the framework repository:

```
conftest.py
pytests
another_file
```

The main repository:

```
dir1
dir2
that_framework/pytests/my_tests
```

How to achieve this without creating another repository and not modifying the framework repository?

Comment: How are you referencing between the two? Is it symlinks? hard links? Copying files directly but adding to the .gitignore? Some info is available [here](http://tdongsi.github.io/blog/2016/02/20/symlinks-in-git/).

Comment: The short answer is no: files inside a repository are inside it, and files outside it are outside it. You can play games with temporarily pointing the working tree to somewhere weird, but this is tricky and probably not going to get you what you want.